# Can't fix "Encryption Credentials Have Expired" for an HP printer

Tags: macos, printing, bonjour

I'm struggling with the configuration of an HP Envy 7920e on MacOS 13.5.

I added the printer but if I use the default driver (HP ENVY Inspire 7900 series-AirPrint 3.0), I get the error "Encryption Credentials Have Expired". I've already tried to renew the certificate (that's valid, by the way) and to re add the printer many times (see here: https://superuser.com/questions/1761248/encryption-credentials-have-expired-when-trying-to-print-to-network-printer-on-m), but such an error persists.

EDIT: I tried to download the certificate from the web interface of the printer manually, but then I can't add it to my keychain (I get Error: -25294)

Comment: I seem to remember that there was an issue with HP rescinding a certificate for their drivers. Perhaps make sure you re-download the latest ones?

Comment: Do you mean the latest driver for MacOS? I do not now where to find it.

Comment: The printer firmware is up to date

Answer (score 1):

Printer software for the HP ENVY Inspire 7900e series can be found at [this link](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hp-smart-for-desktop/id1474276998?mt=12) which opens the macOS App Store.

Comment: I’ve already installed HP Smart. I can use it for printing, however I still can’t print when I add the printer to the OS